# NetSuite Saved Search: How can I create an average daily number of transaction created by a certain individual?

Tags: search, formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm not sure whether this is possible or not, but is it possible to create a saved search that displays the average number of daily transactions created by an individual? For example, I'm trying to create a Productivity KPI and would like to see how many Purchase Requisitions or Purchase Orders are created by an individual per day.

Is this possible within NetSuite? I tried averaging the created by transactions, but the formula field only will average non-text transactions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward. Over what period is the average taken?

Comment: There are two potential scenarios: the average from the first transaction date (only including working days) and from the beginning of a year.

Comment: So the output you are looking for has one row per employee and, ideally, one value per employee?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.